# ImportRDF command uses appdata/local instead of appdata/roaming for repository location

Tags: windows, graphdb

Installed/running Ontotext GraphDB v10.1.0 (free desktop windows).  All working fine, create repositories, run SPARQL, etc.
The server and UI are both loading/running/reporting repositories in the C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Roaming\Graph\data\repositories folder.
However, when running the ImportRdf.cmd utility, its "attaching to"/creating the repository in C:\Users<Username>\AppData\Local\Graph\data\repositories folder instead!?
Tried adding the correct path into C:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\GraphDB Desktop\app\GraphDB Desktop.cfg but makes no difference.
Anyone experienced this/got any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

The data /repository/ directory can be set through the system or config property graphdb.home.data. The default value is the data subdirectory relative to the GraphDB home directory. For example, one way to configure it: Go in bin folder of graphdb distribution and start graphdb with the following command:
./graphdb -Dgraphdb.home="full path to where you want your repo directory".

Comment: The question remains though, why does the graphdb application default to a different path to the importrdf command? (presumably because its using a different config file?)